# why would I need to clean project every time when I do some changes in Adapter in android studio

Tags: android

Whenever I do some changes in the adapter It gives me an Unresolved reference error. so when I clean the project then It works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Delete {projectDir}/.idea/libraries, then go to File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files.